# prove the theorem without any reference to integration

Tags: measure-theory

show that  $A= \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty} E_k$ in theorem $1.41$ and hence prove the theorem without any reference to integration

Here is the outline of theorem $1.41$

**Theorem $1.41$:** Let $\{E_k\}$ be a sequence of measurable sets in $X$,  such that
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mu(E_k)<\infty. $$ Then almost all $x \in X$ lie in  at most finitely many of the sets  $E_k$

**My attempt** : Here  $A$ denote the set of all $x$ which lie  in infinitely many $E_k$

If $x \in A$  then $x \in \bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty} E_k$ for  all $k\le n \in \mathbb{N}$

If $x \notin A$ then  $x \in \bigcup_{k=r}^{n-1} E_k$ $ \implies   x$ is contained  in finitely many $E_k  $for example take $\{E_r,E_{r+1},...,E_{n-1}\}$

after that  i don't know how to proceed further

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x \in \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty} E_k$ then for every $n$ there exist at least one $k \geq n$ such that $x \in E_k$. This implies that $x \in E_k$ for infinitely many values of $k$.

Conversely, if $x \notin \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty} E_k$ then there exists $n$ such that $x \notin E_k$ for any $k \geq n$, so $x \in E_k$ for at most $n-1$ values of $k$.

Finally, $\mu (A) \leq \mu  \bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty} E_k)$ for every $n$ and this gives $\mu (A) \leq \sum\limits_{k=n}^{\infty} \mu (E_k)$. But convergence of the series $\sum\mu(E_k)$ implies that $\sum\limits_{k=n}^{\infty} \mu (E_k) \to 0$ as $ n\to \infty$. Hence, $\mu (A)=0$.

Comment: thanks u @ Kavi sir  but  I have some confusion   what about cases if $x \notin  A$ and  why not $ \mu (A) \le \bigcup_{k=r}^{n-1} E_k?$

Comment: The inequlity is called subadditivity of the measure and it is proved in any book on measure theory. If $x$ does not belong to an intersection then it does not belong to one of the sets in the intersection. @jasmine

Comment: oh !  yes i forgot its , thanks u @Kavi sir